# What is exactly the count argument in MPI receiving functions?

Tags: c, mpi

This question is about the interpretation of the input parameter `count` for receiving operations.

In [one part](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www3/MPI_Recv.html) of the MPI manual it says (`see here` mine):

```
int MPI_Recv(void *buf, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int source, int tag,
             MPI_Comm comm, MPI_Status *status)

Output Parameters

count
    maximum number of elements in receive buffer (integer)  <-------- see here
```

In [other part](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.3/www3/MPI_Sendrecv.html) it says

```
int MPI_Sendrecv(const void *sendbuf, int sendcount, MPI_Datatype sendtype,
                 int dest, int sendtag,
                 void *recvbuf, int recvcount, MPI_Datatype recvtype,
                 int source, int recvtag, MPI_Comm comm, MPI_Status * status)
...
recvcount
    number of elements in receive buffer (integer)   <-------- see here
```

For a long time I ignored the difference in the wording and interpreted them as two ways to say the same thing, that is that is maximum count of elements that can possibly be received.

However, if I read literally `recvcount` (second case) is the number of elements available (allocated) in the buffer, not necessarily the *maximum* number of elements that can be received.
In other words maybe what it is meant is that `recvcount` is the number of elements that the MPI implementation can use to store temporary data and for example end up with garbage in part of it.

There is another context in which it makes a difference: If I don't know exactly what is the number of elements received I could pass `MAX_INT` as argument an ensure the correctness by the logic of the program.
But of course, `MAX_INT` is not the allocated memory in the receiving buffer, it is in principle just a way to say I can receive any number of elements others are sending.

Is there really a difference in the interpretation of `count` (Recv) and `recvcount` (SendRecv)?

**Is it permitted to pass `MAX_INT` in either or both cases?** if the number of receiving elements is not known (locally in a part of the program)

I experimented a bit with OpenMPI and the answer seems to be that passing `MAX_INT` is allowed and work as intended but I don't know if it is the prevalent interpretation.

(The opposite interpretation (count is only the allocated memory) would be sad because it would mean that only allocated buffer with their size can be passed to these functions effectively.)

---

**EDIT:**

To be clear, what I am asking is in this program what is ***in principle*** correct and well defined to receive the whole sent message:

```c
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
 
  int count = 10;
  double xsend[count]; 
  double xrecv[123];

  for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {xsend[i] = (double)i;}

  int rank, nprocs;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nprocs);
  assert (nprocs == 2);

  if(rank == 0) {MPI_Send(xsend, count, MPI_DOUBLE, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);}

  if(rank == 1) {
     MPI_Recv(xrecv, NN, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
     assert( xrecv[9] == 9 );
  }

  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

Which values of `NN` are *semantically* correct to receive the whole message:

1. `NN =  10`
2. `NN =  20`
3. `NN = 123`
4. `NN = 100000`
5. `NN = MAX_INT - 2`
6. `NN = MAX_INT - 1`
7. `NN = MAX_INT`

I understand that option 1. is recommended, and that option 2. and 3. are correct for sure.
My question is whether the other options are well defined.

Comment: The MPICH documentation is not the MPI standard.  Please use https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-4.0/mpi40-report.pdf.  I know that MPICH documentation is often a verbatim copy of the standard, but it's best not to conflate the two.

Comment: @JeffHammond yes. and for completeness in the linked document in page 37 it says “count, size of the receiving buffer”.

Answer (score 1):

The `count` in case of the receive buffer is the size of the receive buffer, expressed in the specified type, and this is an upper bound on the size of the message that can be received. (Note that for the send buffer the count is of course the exact size of the message.) The phrase "maximum number of elements" probably refers to this upper bound behavior.

However, it is confusing and I note that in the most recent standard 4.0 it is not used. https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v4.0a1/www3/MPI_Recv.html

So: 1. you can pass a count that is larger than the size of any message you will receive into that buffer (in which case, call `MPI_Get_count` on the status object), but 2. for proper error reporting you'd better specify the actual size of the buffer, otherwise you may get memory corruption.

EDIT out of the options you're giving, options 1, 2, and 3 are correct: they are 1. at least the size of the message 2. at most the size of the buffer.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. But the real question is, can I pass a count that is larger than the memory available to the buffer?

Comment: The new phrasing is "number of elements in receive buffer", this sounds even more restrictive because it means that I cannot pass `MAX_INT` (or the equivalent for big count) because it is not the size of any buffer. Yes, for debugging is preferable to pass the actual (expected) receiving size, however I would claim that in some contexts the value it is not know, the correctness is ensured by the logic of the program and since something needs to be passed `MAX_INT` seems to be a candidate (except that the wording seems to imply the opposite). How common is to end up passing `MAX_INT`?

Comment: @alfC Yes, you *can* pass a count that is larger than the buffer, but it's not wise to do so. (It may even be undefined behavior.) You say "I cannot pass MAX_INT [...] because it is not the size of any buffer" from which I conclude that you're not getting the difference between buffer and message. You can pass a buffer that is larger than the expected message, but you should use a `count` that accurately gives the size of the buffer. Again, which is not necessarily the size of the message.

Comment: Thank you, that is the real question, if it is undefined behavior to pass `MAX_INT`?. I understand that it is not wise (or not safe) but I would also say that it is too much burden to design a program in which the buffer size is passed all the way to the MPI call point.

Comment: You are doing it wrong by lazily assuming the receive buffer will always be large enough. Not to mention collectives need the exact count (vs an upper bound) and if your program only uses point to point operations, then it is likely far from optimal.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet 1. I am not assuming that the buffer is always large enough, my question is for when I *know* a priori that the buffer is large enough but I don't know the exact count. Programs can have this logic built-in without constantly checking or passing redundant data around. 2. I am not asking about collectives. 3. I don't use point to point operations in general. I added a very specific program at the end of the question so it is more clear.

Comment: @alfC I think you keep conflating buffer size and message size. If the buffer is large enough, pass its exact size (and *not* `MAX_INT`) to the receive routine. Then use `MPI_Get_count` to query the exact message size.

Comment: None of these options are valid since `MPI_Send()` might block until a matching receive is posted.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet There is that too. This ticket seems to be evolving.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, you are correct, I should have been more careful in the example. Now I changed it to avoid the blocking, the question stands.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout  What do you mean by "exact size"? 10 or 123? or something in the range? In you answer you said "you can pass a count that is larger than the size of any message", which in this case is larger than 10, what is not clear in your answer if it can be larger than 123. That is why I put the multiple choice at the end with very specific values. (In the case of SendRecv there is no MPI_Get_count.)

Comment: @alfC I use the phrase "exact size" twice. Please read my words very carefully because I am being quite explicit. In the first case I am talking about the receive buffer, in the second case about the message. In your amended code, that is 123 and 10 respectively. "what is not clear in your answer" Yes it is. You should not specify a number larger than the buffer size. "In the case of SendRecv there is no MPI_Get_count" Wrong. Sendrecv outputs a status object, and you can get the count of that, just like you can get the count of the status of a Recv call.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout, thank you for you very specific answer. To summarize:  for `MPI_SendRecv` and `MPI_Recv` options 1, 2, and 3 are correct and options 4, 5, 6, 7 are incorrect in general. Although they might work accidentally (they work in my tests with OMPI and MPICH).

Comment: You are right about Status, I meant that there is no `MPI_Probe` than can be useful *before* `SendRecv`. Actually I do use the status from Recv and SendRecv to see how much elements are received and "move" the current pointer in the buffer. That is the origin of the question: passing MAX_INT and looking at the Status seemed to be an elegant solution (if not incorrect) where no redundant sizes are passed around. Not all programs are flat like the one in the example, the MPI_Recv can be nested into generic interfaces that pass no redundant information including the size of the buffers.

Comment: I realize that the actual use I have is more complicated, in the sense I am not even passing the head of the allocation. For example, `MPI_Recv(xrecv + 3,`   in which case one borderline option will be `NN = 120` (not 123) and that is even harder to track. But I guess that is material for a separate question. Thank you!

Comment: @alfC If you pass `MAX_INT` you ma have buffer overflow. Conceivably that could corrupt the status object. I disagree with your characterization of the buffer size as "redundant information". That information is really tied to the buffer. It's only because of the design of C (unlike C++, Pascal, Fortran, probably Java, Python) that you need to remember the size of the buffer you created. It's why I vastly prefer writing C++ these days.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout, me too, this is all to write a C++ wrapper for very complex C-MPI calls.. C++ has the same "problem" as C,  even (contiguous) iterators loose information about the "remaining of the buffer". The specifications of MPI are very Fortran centered and it is hard to understand the generalization to C (or C++). If one is too strict in the reading it is as if the only pointer you can pass to any C-MPI call is the head of an allocation together with its allocated size.

Comment: @alfC take a look at MPL, which is a rather nice C++ wrapper library for MPI.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout, thanks for the pointer, I am working on a similar wrapper https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-mpi3 . I hope you like it as well. I learned a lot by writing it and usually take the implementations and the specification to their limits.

Comment: FWIW, MPI C++ bindings are more than deprecated: they were removed from the standard more than a decade ago. They won’t be available from Open MPI 5.